# Change the default route in Asp.net core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have deleted  the valueController and  Created a new Controller in my asp.net core web api project which i named : ***entreprise***

In order to serve  that controller in launch of the project i tried to change the route in **Startup.cs**:

```
app.UseMvc(
            routes => 
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "api",
                 template: "api/{controller=Entreprise}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
            }
            );
```

however , that dosen't change anything !?
when i launch the project again it open this url : https://localhost:44307/api/values
what i want is  https://localhost:44307/api/entreprise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit the `Properties\launchSettings.json` file and modify the `launchUrl` value accordingly.

Comment: i tried that too ,  i added launchUrl and give it a value :api/entreprise but nothing is changed

Comment: could you post the content of the `launchSettings.json` file? Or at least the part below "profiles".

Comment: ah sorry i thought you were speaking about appsettings